# Bipartite graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, bipartite

Consider the following question relative to graph theory :

Let G a bipartite graph. To make the problem more concrete suppose G is the disjoint union of two sets, say I and S. Suppose

- I represents Individuals with name 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
- S represents Skills with name a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h.

So, each individual has *some* skills, for instance,

- individual 1 has skills b, d, g and h,
- individual 2 has skills a, f, and h,
- etc.

[in the example, datas are randomly given].

We aim to build a team composed of the *minimum* number of individuals from *I* in such a way that *every* skill in *S* will be represented in the team, that is for each skill *s* in *S*, there exists a member of the team having the skill *s*.

Does this problem have a name ? Does an efficient algorithm for solving it is known ?

Comment: Sounds like homework syntax.. is this homework ?

Comment: @Yochai Timmer : homework are over during summer holydays ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a **[set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)**
Groups of items from **l** create a subset of **s**

Comment: Thanks. Your reponse gives me the opportunity to check out the classical book on algorithms by Cormen and all :

*The set-covering problem is an abstraction of many commonly arising combinatorial problems. As a simple example, suppose that X represents a set of skills that are needed to solve a problem and that we have a given set of people available to work on the problem. We wish to form a committee, containing as few people as possible, such that for every requisite skill in X, there is a member of the committee having that skill.*

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a minimum set cover problem:

Buy X items from M out of N lots where M is the minimum number of lots you need to obtain all of the X items.

In your example, skills are items and students are lots.

http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/set-cover.shtml

The problem is NP-hard.  The efficient way of solving it is to use the greedy set cover approximation algorithm.